# SICP- defining filter using accumulation

Tags: list, lambda, filter, lisp

So I need to define filter using accumulation, and I need to complete this definition:

```
(define filter
          (lambda (predicate sequence)
              (accumulate ???? null sequence)))
```

I fill in:

```
(lambda (arg result)
         (cons
          (cond ((null? arg) null)
                ((predicate arg) arg)
                (else (filter predicate (cdr sequence))
          (result))
```

But when I test it on (list 1 2 3 4) I get something weird: '((2 ((4) 4) 4) 2 (2 ((4) 4) 4) 4).

Can anyone help me out? What did I do wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Given the SICP definition of `accumulate`:

```
(define (accumulate op initial sequence) 
   (if (null? sequence) 
       initial 
       (op (car sequence) 
           (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence)))))
```

Then `op` is called with two arguments: the interesting element of `sequence` and the result of filtering the rest of the `sequence`, or `initial` if there is no more list.  And you are expected to use `accumulate` as:

```
(define filter
  (λ (predicate sequence)
    (accumulate ???? null sequence)))
```

So, if `????` wants to filter based on `predicate` it should:

- if `predicate` is true on the interesting element of the list, return a list whose `car` is that element, and whose `cdr` is the result of filtering the rest of the list;
- if `predicate` is false on the interesting element of the list, return the result of filtering the rest of the list.

That should be enough for you to write `????`.